# Can all integration be thought of as projections?

Tags: integration

For example, the integral of the function ***f(x)*** could be thought of the projection of ***f*** on the function ***g***, where ***g*** is identically ***1***.

Following this logic, can we think of the multiplication of ***f*** and ***g*** as the area between ***f*** and ***g***, no matter how complicated ***f*** or ***g*** is?

But then this is a bit more if we think of the area between ***f*** and ***g*** as the projection of ***f*** on ***g***, but how do we explain negative area i.e. integrating ***sin(x)***.

I don't know if I was taught the right calculus but I've never seen a textbook that introduces the notion of the integral of ***f*** and ***g*** as the projection of ***f*** on ***g***. Why is that? And if possible, can someone please provide me a good notes on this subject? Treating integration from a projection perspective.

Comment: This is one of the basic ideas behind Riesz representation.

Comment: I won't do that. Integrals are more basic than projections. I mean, if somebody wakes me up at 3 a.m. and abruptly asks me what an integral is, I would probably blabber something about areas under curves, not about projections. This said, it surely is a nice train of ideas that is interesting to explore once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to expand a little, the [Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) has these ideas embedded into it. Generically, on a [Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) of $\Bbb C$-valued functions, you will see

$$\int f(x)\overline{g}(x)\,d\mu(x) $$

(if they have values in $\Bbb R$ the complex conjugation over $g$ disappears)

as an inner product of two functions, which--you may remember from basic vector calculus--was how you talked about projecting one vector onto another

> $$\text{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{u})={\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}\over\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert^2}\mathbf{v}$$

which (if you go back even further) you may remember you had the inner product come in by drawing triangles with the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Albeit, there is no notion of "area" going on with this sort of thing. It measures more just ideas of "amount of one vector in the direction of another." However, you *do* have a nice interpretation of negatives, since we have the formula

> $$\cos(\theta)={\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}\over \lVert\mathbf{u}\rVert\lVert\mathbf{v}\rVert}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors, so that negative numbers just mean the angle is not in the range $-{\pi\over 2}\le\theta\le {\pi\over 2}$.

It's quite natural that you would not have found this in a calculus class, it requires some good amount of linear algebra and proving that that formula gives an inner-product on a space of square-integrable functions is much harder mathematics than just calculus.

Any book on Hilbert spaces which mentions a suitably generalized version of the Riesz representation theorem should be sufficiently satisfying for someone seeking to pursue this line of thought, and any good mathematics library should have $n+1$ books on the subject if you just look in the catalog for "Hilbert spaces." A quick googling of "Hilbert space" yields many results, such as [these notes](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/Hilbert-Spaces.pdf). A proof that $L^2$ of a measure space is a Hilbert space is a classical result in any functional analysis textbook, and follows from the [Minkowski inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).